# Sorting two prime no: before other number. All prime number should be in ascending order and other numbers in descending order

Tags: c

my teacher gave an assignment and I've been trying for more than 5 hrs.Please help me. Here's the question
"Accept an integer n from the user. n lies in the range [1, 50]. Read n integers from the user
and store them in an array. Display this array. Now sort this array such that two prime
numbers appear before one the other numbers. Also, all the prime numbers should be sorted
in ascending order and all the other numbers should be sorted in descending order. Display
the modified array. Write a complete C program to perform all these tasks.

I've tried this. This program won't work if there's much more prime or nonprime number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
void read_array(int [], int);
void display_array(int [], int);
void sortPrimeOrNot(int [], int);
void sortAscending(int [], int);
void sortDescending(int [], int);
bool primecount(int);


void read_array(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter integer %d out of %d:",i+1,n);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
}

bool primecount(int n)
{
    int j=0;
    int test=0;
    if(n<=1)
        return false;
    for(j=2;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(n%j==0)
            test++;
    }
    if(test==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void sortPrimeOrNot(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i,j,k,prime=0,nonprime=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(primecount(arr[i]))
            prime++;
        else
            nonprime++;
    }
    int arr1[prime],arr2[nonprime];
    j=0;
    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(primecount(arr[i]))
           {
               arr1[j]=arr[i];
               j++;
           }
        else
            {
                arr2[k]=arr[i];
                k++;
            }
    }
    sortAscending(arr1,prime);
    sortDescending(arr2,nonprime);
    j=0;
    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if((i+1)%3==0 && nonprime>0)
        {
            arr[i]=arr2[j];
            j++;
            nonprime--;
        }
        else if(prime>0)
        {
            arr[i]=arr1[k];
            k++;
            prime--;
        }
    }

}

void display_array(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d",arr[i]);
    }
}
void sortAscending(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
                int temp=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortDescending(int arr[], int n)
{

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]<arr[j+1])
            {
                int temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i,n,arr[50];
    printf("Enter a positive integer in the range [1, 50]:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<1 || n>50)
    {
        printf("Invalid input.");
        return 1;
    }
    read_array(arr,n);
    printf("\nOriginal Array: ");
    display_array(arr,n);
    printf("\nModified Array: ");
    sortPrimeOrNot(arr,n);
    display_array(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you build the program? What happens when you run it? What input do you give the program? What output do you get? What output are you supposed to get? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: To summarize my previous comment: When you say that the "program won't work if there's much more prime or nonprime number", what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer. The question is "muddy" as the directions to "put 2 primes before one of the other numbers" is imprecise and makes no sense if only 1 or 2 values are entered.

Look carefully at the loop counters in your two sorting functions, and the index values they generate. Here's a stripped down version of one:

```
    int n = 8;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            printf( "%d  %d  %d\n", i, j, n );
```

This "print debugging" shows that this "sorting" does not work. Since the two arrays are not sorted, it's unlikely it will be "zippered" together to satisfy the requirements.

For a simple bubble sort, try something like this:

```
void sortAscending(int arr[], int n) {
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        for( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
            if( arr[ j ] > arr[ i ] ) {
                int temp = arr[ i ];
                arr[ i ] = arr[ j ];
                arr[ j ] = temp;
            }
}
```

Do the arithmetic in the `for()` loop, not when using the counters as array indexes.
This applies to both sorting functions.

Far better would be to use `qsort()`, but that may be for another day down the road.

When "zippering" the prime and non-prime arrays, the loop increments `i`, but will **not** copy a value to the destination if the source array being tapped for this iteration is exhausted. Here's a quick version of the additional code needed:

```
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
        if((i+1)%3==0 && nonprime>0) { // Abundant nonprimes?
            arr[i]=arr2[j++];
            nonprime--;
        } else if(prime>0) { // abundant primes?
            arr[i]=arr1[k++];
            prime--;
        } else { // Oops! wanted is depleted, so copy from other array...
            if( !prime ) {
                arr[i]=arr2[j++];
                nonprime--;
            } else {
                arr[i]=arr1[k++];
                prime--;
            }
        }
```

PS: Neither instance of `scanf();` verifies the return value from that function call. It is dangerous to continue processing when the user may have entered garbage data.